# build error cannot find GetStateValidity.h

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to perform the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/motion_planning_environment/Tutorials/Tutorial%20A) that checks the collision for a given robot state. However, once I try to build the arm_navigation_tutorials package I receive the following build error:

/home/wouter/ros/workspace/arm_navigation_tutorials/src/get_state_validity.cpp:2:56: fatal error: planning_environment_msgs/GetStateValidity.h: No such file or directory

I downloaded the debian package ros-diamondback-motion-planning-common that includes the 'planning_environment_msgs' package and added opt/ros/diamondback/stacks to my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

My ROS_PACKAGE_PATH thus includes my workspace, opt/ros/diamondback/stacks and opt/ros/electric/stacks because I am using ROS electric on Ubuntu 11.04. So rosmake should be able to find GetStateVAlidity.h.

Do you have any idea why rosmake cannot find GetStateValidity.h?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11279/build-error-cannot-find-getstatevalidity.h/) by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2011-09-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That message definition, along with many others, were moved (in electric) to arm_navigation_msgs, as described here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation. That tutorial hasn't been updated to electric.  It may or may not work if you replace that header location along with changing "environment_server_right_arm" to "planning_scene_validity_server".  However, you'll also have to use the planning description configuration wizard to build the necessary launch files, and then launch them.

Alternatively, you could use diamondback.  You probably shouldn't be including both /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks and /opt/ros/electric/stacks in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH--you can't generally mix and match packages from different releases.

---

Originally posted by [Paul Vernaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/240/paul-vernaza/) with karma: 181 on 2011-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3